# How to match this in an if statement

Tags: python, django

I am working with Django formwizard. In this part I want to use an if statement:

```
def get_form_initial(self, step):
        if step =='2':
                x = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') or {}
                if x['Color']  == 'Red':
```

No matter what I try I never get x['Color'] matching 'Red'

I checked and x gets the value:

```
{'Color': <Products: Red>}
```

I also tried x['Color']['Products'] == 'Red' (and also a lot of other options) but this resulted in an error message.

This is probably easy, but I cannot figure it out......

Comment: Can you debug the line of code and expand the dictionary until you find the attribute that is the text 'Red'? Or just print(x['Color']['Products'].__dict__()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify the model and forms that you are using I will just be getting here, but I would expect it has to be something like this:

```
def get_form_initial(self, step):
        if step =='2':
                x = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') or {}
                if x['Color'].color  == 'Red':
```

The `x['Color']` returns a `Products` object from what I can gather and I cannot see here what properties it has.
To debug you could try printing `x['Color'].__dict__`

Comment: Wolph and Victor thank you both! I was looking in the wrong direction. Problem solved :-)